# Where should I ask about lowering browser CPU usage?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, browsers

I looked, but I did not find any browser or Internet groups. Where should this question be located? It's not a web app or Internet of things.

> I am tired of how my Firefox/Mozilla browser keeps using more resources than I feel it needs to. I find that lots of pages are doing more than I want them to. What I would like is some method or addon which allows me to end what a page gets for CPU, but will keep it in memory. So the page will display and links will work, but it won't update.
>
> I've tried hibernation and all it does is display a place holder for the page and unloads it from memory, then when it wakes up, reloads the page.
>
> Am I being too greedy in what I want? Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for an alternative browser, then [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is probably what you want, as noted by @Robert Longson. Be aware that SoftwareRecs.SE is pretty strict with questions, so be sure to read its [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [question quality guidelines](http://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/) before you post your question there.

If you want a general way of lowering CPU usage on a browser, even if it is a specific one, then I think [Super User](https://superuser.com/) may be where you'd like to go, as people there can provide different approaches to solutions.

Comment: The super user group sounds like its more of where I should be asking, thanks for the assist.

Comment: I try to give some time for answers to fill in, just in case there is a better one. So tomorrow if yours is still the best then I will

Comment: +1[­](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

While recommendation questions are off-topic in most Stack Exchange sites there is one that might be suitable if you're looking specifically for a browser add-on: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). It has pretty strict requirements for questions to be on topic so be sure to read its [help centre](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/) carefully.

Outside of Stack Exchange altogether, you can search for add-ons on [Firefox's add-ons page](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/) perhaps you'll find a suitable one there without having to ask a question at all.

Comment: I did look at the add-ons and nothing seemed to offer what I wanted. They were just unloading the page but keeping its tab. Then to awake they would either load from cache or reload.